# Assume AC Phase has zero potential

Tags: ac

The neutral null wire is said to have potential 0 while the phase wire has a varying potential. It seems that the potential 0 for ground or null wire is just a definition. One can define its potential to be 10. Nothing will change. Now can we assign the phase wire a constant potential 0 instead and assume that the null wire has a varying potential. Will anything change? Is there any physical or experimental clue forcing us to assume the null wire has a constant potential?

We can assign any constant velocity to a free floating stone in space (for example outside solar system). But we cannot assign a varying velocity to it because acceleration is inherent and is physically determinable using an accelerometer. Is the same true for potential. Can we assume the null wire has a varying potential and instead assume the phase wire has zero potential?

Comment: You can test this theory easily by grabbing the black wire and seeing what happens.

Comment: So you believe the sun orbits the Earth?

Comment: @jdv: A bird sits on a phase wire and nothing happens.

Comment: @EMFields no because an accelerometer reveals that's a bad choice. If accelerometers could not reveal nor not any other tools then yes we could assume so.

Comment: @iranano and a neon probe connected to a live wire reveals that defining it as zero volts is just as bad of a choice.

Comment: If an eagle or vulture finds a way to touch both wires... the point is no one knows what point you are making. Yes, it is convention, and yes much of the math would work out if you swapped hot and neutral, or used a different levels for "0". But other stuff would fail spectacularly because it is a convention.

Comment: @EMFields I missed the irony in your comment :-)  No. I want to see if this is a convention out of human life limitations or there is pure physics justification behind this definition excluding human life limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you're in a commercial building in the USA fed by 480 and you have your own 120/240V transformer, which is not grounded.  Other than that, you are wired to modern code with all EMT conduit. The conduit, boxes and service panel enclosure are the ground, bonded to a ground rod driven into earth.

All the neutrals go to the neutral bus, which is insulated from the panel chassis (ground).  However, there is a metal strap, bonding the neutral bus to ground.  This is the only place neutral is bonded to ground. There are no ground-neutral or ground-hot faults.  With me so far?

Remove the bond.  Replace it with a 12V car battery.   What changes?

You've introduced a 12VDC bias between neutral and ground.  It's still 0 VAC though, and the little neon 3-lamp tester will give 2 amber lights and no red. (neon doesn't work on DC).

OK, now replace it with a 3V buck-boost transformer.  Now you have a 3VAC bias between neutral and ground.  L1-neutral will be 240v, L1-ground will be 117V, L2-ground will be 123V.  They could just put a 3v tap on the supply transformer.

It's all arbitrary.  We humans **make it up**.

How far can we push it?  Bond the ground to L1.  Now L1-ground is 0v, neutral-ground is 120v and L2-ground is 240v. Illegal?  Perhaps.  But no less safe than Europe, which has 240V hot-ground.  Weird?  Not compared to 3-phase: They ground anywhere they please - in the middle (wye), on a corner, or halfway down a side (high leg/wild leg).  Or not at all (delta).

So why do we "make it up" the way we make it up?

A bunch of people in offices picking through thousands of fatality reports, trying to compromise with the clamoring of builders, manufacturers and electricians to make things cheaper for them, and come up with something easy.

Comment: So do you say that we can assume the phase wire has a constant potential 0 and the null wire has a varying potential?

Comment: If you are holding onto the "hot" wire and not touching anything else, that would be your worldview, yes. That is a normal day at work for a lineman. The wire you're repairing is neutral, and the rest of the world is hot and lethal to you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faoA9Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In most countries the electrical utility grounds one of the wires from the local step-down transformer. This "neutralises" the wire as there is now no potential relative to earth. The live wire, on the other hand, has full voltage between it and earth.

If the earth connection is omitted you don't really have a "neutral" any more and the two wires can float to any voltage.

Earth or ground is taken as reference in much the same way that "sea-level" is taken as reference for altitude.

Comment: And can we instead assume earth has a varying potential? About sea level, well, one can assign a varying height to it, for example one can assume its level depends on time. it's abnormal but mathematically possible because its just a definition, a hypothesis.

Comment: No. Earth's potential, measured over a large area, is generally taken as zero. There can be local changes in earth potential in the event of large ground currents - lightning strikes, for example.

Comment: It's a definition, not a hypothesis.  The Earth is defined to be at 0V, and everything else is measured relative to it.  This has a couple of advantages - (1) The Earth tends to be nearby, wherever you are - if I were to define 0V to be the voltage of the live wire in my house, then that is of no use to you. (2) Since people stand on the Earth, it tells you how likely you are to be electocuted if you touch a given wire.

Comment: @SimonB well I do not complain about the definition. I'm asking if there is any pure physics criterion for such definition excluding human life limitations. As I explained in the question, a varying speed as a definition is not acceptable because acceleration is not determined by definition. I thought there may be something similar for potential.

Comment: @iranano It's just a convention.  It's actually only possible to measure the voltage *between* two things.  It's not even meaningful to talk about the voltage of one thing alone, nor to measure the voltage between to completely unconnected things.  For an isolated appliance, such as one running on batteries, it's not even possible to measure the voltage to Earth.  Instead you just have to choose one part of the circuit - traditionally the negative terminal of the battery - and call that 0V instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you touch the neutral wire, you don't get shocked, if you touch the live wire, you do. So objectively there is a difference.

Of course, you can define the live wire to be at 0V and say that the Earth has shocked you instead. This may even make sense as a model in some cases (like birds sitting on the wires), just as Sun going around Earth makes sense when discussing daily cycles. On a larger scale however, such models will fail: there is no 50Hz EM field generated by Earth (or 60Hz if your Earth is US-based :).